# why do i get "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare funcName()" on one vhost but not the other?

Tags: php, apc

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include('inc/functions.php');
include('inc/functions.php');
include('inc/functions.php');

function funcName() {}

echo 'all done!';
```

inc/functions.php defines `funcName`.

I run that code on one virtual host and I get a `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare funcName()` error. I run it on another virtual host on the same server and I don't. In fact, I get an "all done!" message. inc/functions.php is the same on both servers. The .htaccess is the same on both servers. Both virtual hosts are running PHP 5.3.2 (which I waaay EOL, I am aware).

If I put in an echo in `inc/functions.php` the server that doesn't give me a fatal error outputs that echo statement 3x times, showing that that file is, in fact, being included 3x times.

[APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is installed on the server if that helps. Since that does opcode cache'ing that maybe that was kinda masking the errors but if that were the case then it seems like [clearing the APC cache](https://ma.ttias.be/clear-apc-cache-php/) would make the behavior more consistent but it doesn't..

Comment: I suppose one VH is configuered to surpress Errors

Comment: And finally why you want to redeclare that function anyway? To override methods better use classes and extend them.

Comment: @Jeff - I don't *want* to redeclare the function. I'm trying to code review a coworkers code and on my vhost it produces a fatal error but not on his vhost and I'm trying to figure out why. If the coworkers environment isn't displaying fatal errors then he could inadvertently introduce fatal errors into his code without realizing it. And try as I may to do a good and thorough code review I may miss issues that he could have caught during development.

Comment: @Jeff - and as for the possibility that one VH is set to suppress errors...  sure that's a possibility. But a fatal error is a fatal error is a fatal error. Even if errors weren't being output to the screen it shouldn't get to the very end of the program. The fatal error should prevent the "all done!" line from displaying and it isn't..

Comment: good point: _"The fatal error should prevent the "all done!" line from displaying"_ To be honest: I'm afraid I cant help, sorry!